# how to use qt webkit page pagination

Tags: qt, pagination, webkit, qt4.7

I try to using pagination in the `qwebpage` class to paginate a big html file.
any one use this before? I don't known that I am using correct way or it still supported in `qwebpage` class. my qt library is based on 4.7.4.
code like below:

```
this->page()->setPagination(pagination);
```

Comment: Where did you find such a function? I can't find it in all the docs

Comment: got from github webkit master